# Approach to use:- Manual notification or using Push Notification via web service

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

As title suggest I want to know which approach will be best suited for my situation.Here is what I need.

In my app I am having a list of events. when clicking on any event from list, it will take user to event details page. On that page I have a Remind Me button on press of which user will be notified few hours/days before event. I want to know which of the two approach will be better.

**First Approach**

I register an alarm manually with the system which will get trigger according to the time which I will provide at the time of setting alarm.

**Second Approach**

I should use a web service along with push notification and when push is received show notification to the user.

Comment: Your first approach works,  but your second approach is probably better in the long run, especially when you want to implement other features in your backend later on.

Comment: However don't use the `AlarmManager`, use the Job API. The Job API works much better because it already takes care of a lot of stuff for you.

Comment: can you give an example for that

Comment: Just look at the documentation of the `GcmNetworkManager`. Scheduling a One-off task is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first approach is sufficient. A local notification is all you need in this case. Using the second approach is definitely overkill. The benefits of the first method are it will work offline and it save you cost to send a remote notification.

Comment: will it work properly if alarms set for multiple events?This is my main concern

Comment: Yes... Multiple events at a different timing will definitely works.

Comment: If you want multiple notification at the same timing, you can set a different notification ID

Comment: Then no issue. What's stopping you from accepting the answer? Could you please share your concern?

Comment: I will accept after implementation as I have not implemented yet

Comment: will I be getting notification even when app is closed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115950/getting-notification-even-after-notification-time-has-passed-using-alarm-manager I am having this issue with my notification implementation. Can you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is the best. If you go with the web approach there can be chances that the user isn't using data-plan. And yes it will surely work for multiple instances. Instead of relying solely on alarms. You can use the calendar API and set a reminder. You can set multiple reminder with alarms that way.
I hope it helps.